# Align button with text and icon to start from right

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button, layout

I am creating part of a program in Flutter running on an Android emulator but am stumped on how to align this button's position to start from the right so it doesn't overflow off the screen when the button text changes from "Start" to "Mark as Complete". I have tried to add the `MainAxisAlignment.end` property to the Row, aligning the text using `textAlign` and even using a variable size for the Card background, but none seem to be working. I would appreciate some guidance on how to achieve this.

Here is my current code:

```
                   TextButton(                                        
                     style: ButtonStyle(                                                
                      shape: 
                           MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder> (                        
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                        side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      )),
                    ),
                    // ignore: avoid_print
                    onPressed: () => print("sdf"),
                    child: const Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 5, 10, 5),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_circle_right_outlined,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(103, 80, 164, 1),
                            size: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 10, 5),
                          child: Text(
                            "Start", //"Mark as Complete",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(103, 80, 164, 1),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              letterSpacing: 1.0,
                              fontFamily: "Roboto",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Can you include more about parent widget, a sample snippet from scaffold body will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I find an Expanded widget comes in handy.

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 4, //whatever value you think it should be
          child: TextButton()],
        ),
)
```

or you can use a Wrap around the Text in your TextButton.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! Just had to wrap it with Expanded twice , once as a parent and once as a child of Row().